# Get length of "EMPTY SPACE" in the string

Tags: java, string

I have to read a flat file which is not properly structured and I need to read it by the size of the indent in a line.

```
  Element TestData*
     Content Particle Particle_3*
        Element TestData1*
           Content Particle Particle_62*
```

Above is my structure of the flat file. I need to read the empty leading spaces before the text.

The expected result to be:
Length of Empty space of 1st line = 2
Length of Empty space of 2nd line = 5
Length of Empty space of 3rd line = 8
Length of Empty space of 4th line = 11

Any help would be great...!!!
Thanks.

Comment: Read the text file line by line, Use BufferedReader and thre is a method .readLine(). Why do you need to give empty space to read the lines ?

Comment: Questions asking for help must include a summary of **the work you've done** so far to solve the problem, and **a description of the difficulty** you are having solving it. Please read [_What topics can I ask about here?_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to know more.

Comment: Well, you could iterate over the characters of each line and count until you hit a non-whitespace char. Are there only spaces or could the line also contain tabs? If tabs could be present, how would you count those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might work:

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args){

    try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("./testfile.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)){

      int lineNr = 0;
      String line;

      while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
        lineNr++;
        int spaces = 0;
        for (int i=0;i<line.length();i++){
          if (line.charAt(i) == ' '){
            spaces++;
          }
          else{
            break;
          }
        }

        System.out.println("line "+lineNr+" has "+spaces+" leading spaces:"+line);
      }

    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

}
```

Output:

```
line 1 has 2 leading spaces:  Element TestData*
line 2 has 5 leading spaces:     Content Particle Particle_3*
line 3 has 8 leading spaces:        Element TestData1*
line 4 has 11 leading spaces:           Content Particle Particle_62*
```